# .join ( ) Only Works in console.log ( )

Tags: javascript, arrays, join

When I use the console.log( ) function to join this array it returns the combined array, but when I use the .join( ) function outside of console.log( ), it does not combine the array. How do I combine this array to create a single string with no comma outside of console.log( )?

```
var string = stringArray.map(string => "&sources=" + string);
console.log(stringURL.join(''));

stringURL.join('');
console.log(stringURL);
```

Comment: String are immutable. You should reassign it. `stringURL = stringURL.join('');`

Answer (score 3):

`.join()` is a function that returns the joined string. So when you call it, it calculates the value and then returns it.

Store it in a variable.

```
var joinedString = stringURL.join('');
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that *stringURL.join('');* does modify stringURL but give a new string. so the best is to make

```
var new_string = stringURL.join('');
console.log(new_string);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can't have a variable name called string, it's protected. Change it to something else and it will work.

[Here's a complete list of reserved keywords](http://www.javascripter.net/faq/reserved.htm) and [here is an explanation from Mozilla MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Talk:JavaScript/Reference/Reserved_Words)

```
var mappedString = stringArray.map(string => "&sources=" + string);
console.log(mappedString.join(''));

var joinedString = mappedString.join('')

console.log(joinedString);
```

That should do!

Comment: I'm going to assume the use of `string` is a typo as `stringURL`  is used consistently in the rest of the code (which works as it should).

Comment: In fact, you _can_ have a variable called `string`, heck, you can even have a variable called `String`! It will have the (possibly unpleasant!) side-effect of overwriting the String-class with whatever you assign to it, but it's possible.